# Pitchers with postseason home run

Tags: baseball, trivia, mlb, postseason

Can you please list all pitchers who have hit a home run in the history of MLB playoffs?

Bonus: Include position players who started a postseason game as the pitcher and hit a homerun

Comment: This is a pretty broad trivia piece. Consider that you have over 100 years of history to pull from. I don't think there is a reasonable limiter here.

Comment: Another close vote came in after I answered.  Based on [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223458), "it's a safe bet that the question is not too broad".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Baseball-Reference.com [Batting Game Finder](http://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/game_finder.cgi?type=b) has data going back to 1903.  To get the list of pitchers who have hit home runs in the postseason, make the following setting changes on that page:

- select "Find Players with Most Matching Games in Multiple Years"
- select "Postseason"
- for "Batter's Defensive Position", make sure only "P" is checked (this will include any position player who hit a home run in a game that he made an appearance as a pitcher)
- under "Select Additional Criteria Games Must Match", add a criteria for "HR >= 1"

After you click on "[Get Report](http://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/game_finder.cgi?type=b#gotresults&as=result_batter&offset=0&match=gmatchCar&suffix=_post&min_year_game=1903&max_year_game=2014&series=any&series_game=any&playoffs=&WL=any&game_length=any&team_lg=&opp_id=&opp_lg=&bats=any&throws=any&HV=any&game_site=&temperature_min=0&temperature_max=120&wind_speed_min=0&wind_speed_max=90&wind_direction_tolf=1&wind_direction_tocf=1&wind_direction_torf=1&wind_direction_fromlf=1&wind_direction_fromcf=1&wind_direction_fromrf=1&wind_direction_ltor=1&wind_direction_rtol=1&wind_direction_unknown=1&precipitation_unknown=1&precipitation_none=1&precipitation_drizzle=1&precipitation_showers=1&precipitation_rain=1&precipitation_snow=1&sky_unknown=1&sky_sunny=1&sky_cloudy=1&sky_overcast=1&sky_night=1&sky_dome=1&pos_1=1&exactness=any&GS=anyGS&GF=anyGF&lineup_position=&number_matched=1&orderby=HR&c1criteria=HR&c1gtlt=gt&c1val=1&c2criteria=&c2gtlt=eq&c2val=0&c3criteria=&c3gtlt=eq&c3val=0&c4criteria=&c4gtlt=eq&c4val=0&c5criteria=&c5gtlt=eq&c5val=1.0&c6criteria=&location=pob&locationMatch=is&pob=&pod=&pcanada=&pusa=&firstgames=&startgames=&lastgames=&firstteamgames=&startteamgames=&lastteamgames=&ajax=1&submitter=1)", you will find 19 pitchers who have hit postseason home runs.  But it only shows 10 of those names, since you have to subscribe to see the entire list.  Just go back to the search form, click the "Use ascending order" box, and click "[Get Report](http://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/game_finder.cgi?type=b#gotresults&as=result_batter&offset=0&match=gmatchCar&suffix=_post&min_year_game=1903&max_year_game=2014&series=any&series_game=any&playoffs=&WL=any&game_length=any&team_lg=&opp_id=&opp_lg=&bats=any&throws=any&HV=any&game_site=&temperature_min=0&temperature_max=120&wind_speed_min=0&wind_speed_max=90&wind_direction_tolf=1&wind_direction_tocf=1&wind_direction_torf=1&wind_direction_fromlf=1&wind_direction_fromcf=1&wind_direction_fromrf=1&wind_direction_ltor=1&wind_direction_rtol=1&wind_direction_unknown=1&precipitation_unknown=1&precipitation_none=1&precipitation_drizzle=1&precipitation_showers=1&precipitation_rain=1&precipitation_snow=1&sky_unknown=1&sky_sunny=1&sky_cloudy=1&sky_overcast=1&sky_night=1&sky_dome=1&pos_1=1&exactness=any&GS=anyGS&GF=anyGF&lineup_position=&number_matched=1&orderby=HR&order_by_asc=1&c1criteria=HR&c1gtlt=gt&c1val=1&c2criteria=&c2gtlt=eq&c2val=0&c3criteria=&c3gtlt=eq&c3val=0&c4criteria=&c4gtlt=eq&c4val=0&c5criteria=&c5gtlt=eq&c5val=1.0&c6criteria=&location=pob&locationMatch=is&pob=&pod=&pcanada=&pusa=&firstgames=&startgames=&lastgames=&firstteamgames=&startteamgames=&lastteamgames=&ajax=1&submitter=1)" again to see the rest of the names.

The 19 pitchers are:

- Dave McNally (hit 2 postseason home runs)
- Bob Gibson (hit 2 postseason home runs)
- Kerry Wood
- Bucky Walters
- Rick Sutcliffe
- Jeff Suppan
- Jose Santiago
- Rosy Ryan
- Mickey Lolich
- Ken Holtzman
- Jesse Haines
- Don Gullett
- Mudcat Grant
- Mike Cuellar
- Steve Carlton
- Lew Burdette
- Joe Blanton
- Jack Bentley
- Jim Bagby

**Edit**: Since the original answer, [3 more pitchers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Major_League_Baseball_pitchers_who_have_hit_home_runs_in_the_postseason) have had postseason homeruns:

- Travis Wood
- Jake Arrieta
- Brandon Woodruff

Comment: Added the edit section for the missing 3 pitchers since you posted your answer. I was able to see them on baseball-reference.com as well, but had to change year span to look from 1969 to 2019 and look for the results on both ascending and descending order. Didn't add those 3 guys to your list as you can't see all of them by the procedure you mentioned to find since there is more than 20 players to achieve the feat now. Using the Wikipedia link I added as my reference (which has been created after you posted your answer) works much easier now.